# Unable to make raw SQL calls from Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core

I am working on a project where I am moving specific rows from a table between multiple different environments. The table has an `Identity` column and when I try to move it I get an error that `Identity_Insert` is off.

Looking at several of the questions on here one of the solutions has been to call `Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()`, `ExecuteSqlRaw()` or the async variations of them. However when I attempt to call them in my code I get an error indicating

> 'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteSqlCommand' and no accessible extension method could be found

and the only execute option I even see in the intellisense list is `CreateExecutionStrategy`.

I have the Nuget packages `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and the tools and abstractions packages all installed so I am not sure why I cannot see any of these options which are present and set to version 5.0.16.

Any ideas on what package I may be missing in order to access these methods? I even tried installing the nuget package for EF6 but that didn't help either.

Code snippet

```
using (SchoolSystemContext sourceContext = new SchoolSystemContext(sourceDB), targetContext = new SchoolSystemContext(targetDB))
            {
                var student = sourceContext.Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StudentId == 1000);

                if (student == null)
                {
                    try
                    { 
                        targetContext.Students.Add(student);
                        targetContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET Identity_Insert Student ON");
                        targetContext.SaveChanges();
                        targetContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET Identity_Insert Student OFF");
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                    
                }
            }
```

Error message Image
[image]

Comment: Share your code snippet + stacktrace

Comment: @drum I have added the code snippet and a screenshot of the errors that I am receiving. I don't get a stacktrace because the errors block the project from building or running. If i try to resolve the issue with Ctrl + period the only option I receive is to introduce a local variable which doesn't actually fix the problem. There are no namespaces suggested for import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Entirely sure what changed but coming back to this a few days ago I rebuilt the Application again and it was still giving me errors about ExecuteSqlCommand() not being defined, but I also added in calls to Database.OpenConnection() and Database.CloseConnection() which were missing originally. Once those were added in I could see the ExecuteSqlRaw() Method in intellisense and inserting that into the code fixed my issues.